# Understanding the return statement.

Tags: javascript

I have looked at many examples but still cant figure how the return statement works.

```
 function One() {
   var newVal = 0;
   Too();
   console.log(newVal);
 }

 function Too(newVal) {
   ++newVal; 
   return(newVal);
 }
```

Shouldn't this print 1 to the console? What I'm really trying to do is to have function Too increase newVal by 1 every time it's called. But I cant even figure out how to get the return statement to work. I should mention I don't want to use global variables. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're not passing anything to the `Too` function when you call it - `Too();`...yet `Too` expects an argument that it modifies. And you're not even doing anything with the return value of `Too()`. And literals are passed by value, to keep it simple, so you can't pass an integer, modify it, and expect the original reference to change - you'll have to actually utilize the return value to do anything useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. The `return` statement establishes what the value of the function invocation will be in the calling environment when control returns there. Since your calling environment doesn't *use* the return value, there's no net effect.

Here's how you'd get the value back:

```
newVal = Too(newVal);
```

If you want to make a function that acts as a counter, such that each time you call it you get a new number back, you can do something like this:

```
var counter = function(initial) {
  var c = initial || 0;
  return function() {
    return c++;
  };
}(0);
```

What that does is use an anonymous function to set up a persistent environment for *another* function, which is returned from the outer one when it's (immediately) invoked. The returned function can then be called to return a new value from its private counter (the variable "c"):

```
var currentCount = counter();
alert(currentCount); // 0, the first time
currentCount = counter();
alert(currentCount); // 1, and so on
```

Comment: I would like to thank every one for there answers. This has really help me to better understand the return statement.

Answer (score 4):

> Shouldn't this print 1 to the console?

No. The `newVal` inside `Too` is not the `newVal` inside `One`. They're completely separate.

> What I'm really trying to do is to have function Too increase newVal by 1 every time it's called.

It can't, JavaScript doesn't have any mechanism for passing variables by reference like some other languages do (C#'s `ref` and `out` arguments, for instance). The closest you can come is to pass in a reference to an object and modify the object's state (which is really quite different and I won't go into it here as it would confuse things :-) ).

None of which has anything to do with the `return` statement.

The simplest way to do what you were describing is this:

```
function One() {
    var newVal = 0;
    newVal = Too(newVal);
    console.log(newVal);
}

function Too(arg) {
    ++arg; 
    return arg;
}
```

Here's what happens when we call `One`:

1. A local variable called `newVal` is created.
2. Its value is set to `0`.
3. A copy of its *value* is passed into the function `Too` as an argument. This has no link back to the `newVal` variable.
4. `Too` is called, accepting that value in its `arg` argument (arguments in JavaScript are effectively local variables).
5. `Too` increments the value in `arg`.
6. `Too` returns a copy of the value held by `arg` as its *return value*.
7. The return value of `Too` is assigned to the variable `newVal`.
8. We output that value (by passing it into `console.log`).

Comment: They are completely separate this time at least, mentioning a bit about global variables in JavaScript might also be helpful here. (Especially since JavaScript has a funny way of handling them)

Comment: The last thing I want to do, given the OP's current level of understanding, is start talking about closures. :-)

Comment: me - *~whistles like he didn't notice anything~* (*edit* - this is not a joke about downvoting; I didn't of course.)

Comment: Just to assure you, T.J.: It wasn't me!

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Didn't think it was. :-) It's fine, I just want to know what I'm missing is all. But I guess I'm not going to. Time for bed anyway. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If a function return a value you need to call that function in your `console.log` or capture the returned value.

```
function One() {
   var newVal = 0;

   console.log(Too(newVal));
 }

 function Too(newVal) {
   ++newVal; 
   return(newVal);
 }
```